# How to unsigned operations with negative values work in WebAssembly?

Tags: webassembly

I'm looking at unsigned operations with negative parameters, and I don't know what it actually does.

For example, i32.div_u does some weird stuff. This comes out as 0

```
i32.const 2
i32.const -3
i32.div_u
```

But if you flip it

```
i32.const -2
i32.const 3
i32.div_u
```

it comes out as 1431655764. I suspect this some sort of wrap or something. But if you try two negatives it'll either come out as 0 or 1 depending on if the first parameter is less than the second. Like -5 and -4 gives 0 but -4 and -5 gives 1.

Of course this isn't just for division, this is just the simplest one to show it on. This sort of thing is affected by all the _u operations, but I suspect they all work in a similar way. Can anybody explain what is done with these negative numbers to make the operations work?